# Transfer from Geneva Airport to La Thuile

Tags: airport-transfer, transportation, solo-travel, night-transport, skiing

I am trying to book a last minute ski trip for the Easter weekend. I am about to purchase my flight tickets, but I'm unable to do so, because I am not sure how I can get myself from Geneva Airport to La Thuile. I checked [the previous questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=la%20thuile) here, but they don't answer this question. I googled and checked some bus/train websites, and didn't find any options available for landing at 21:35 and flying back at 7:00. I found [this one](https://booking.suntransfers.com/booking?step=1&iata=GVA&hash=b6403e9c-5fd9-11e9-bc82-06d54f4a71e4) which has some horrendous prices for one person.

Could you please let me know if there is any reasonably-priced way for getting transfer to/from La Thuile from/to Geneva Airport so that I could make this trip happen? (My dates are *April 18th arrival at 21:35 or 23:25*, and *22nd departure at 7am* if that matters)

Comment: You've picked two places 60+ miles apart and separated by the highest mountain in the Alps and you want to travel between them late at night or early morning. The only viable route is via the Mont Blanc tunnel. Nothing will be cheap.

Comment: There are at least two places called _La Thuile_ in the region, one on the French side and one on the Italian side. Which one are you going to? (Maybe only one of them is a good place for skiing, I wouldn't know.) Either way it's a small place which is quite far from the airport. Have you contacted the place where you're staying? Many places will arrange a pick-up, although the late/early hours and the distance means that they're unlikely to go as far as the airport, but you might find some workable intermediate point.

Comment: It's the Itanian side @Gilles, I wanted to book my flights before booking a place which would be an AirBnb or a hostel which probably wouldn't have transfer I guess... :-/

Comment: @ReddHerring I'm not familiar with the Alps, I picked this one because I asked a friend (ski instructor) and she suggested this one. I find the whole process of planning this kind of an adventurous trip very complicated! Since I haven't booked anything, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Neeku I can personally recommend La Plagne in the Isere Valley. Trains run up the valley and stop at Aime from where you can get a taxi or perhaps bus to the resort. I believe you can get a connecting train from Lyon airport, and perhaps Chambery. I've picked up the return train from Bourg at the top of the valley - getting a taxi from La Plagne was no problem. Skiing's great at La Plagne. Get an apartment above 1800m if at all possible, but time is short.

Answer (score 1):

You’re going at night, the only option after searching around it a taxi. You’re looking at $300+ per person.